# Javascript Memory Leak in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

When I run the following code in node.js I get the following error message:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory

//Running this code causes program to run out of memory.
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        readFile(files[i]); 
}

//log each line of file to console
function readFile(data){
    var lines = fs.readFileSync(data).toString().split('\n');
    for(var k = 0; k < lines.length; k++){
        console.log(lines[k]);
    }
}
```

But, if I change the readFile function and take the `console.log(lines[k])` out of the for loop, the fatal error goes away. Why is that? And how can I fix the original code so it stops running out of memory?

```
function readFile(data){
    var lines = fs.readFileSync(data).toString().split('\n');
    var string = ''
    for(var k = 0; k < lines.length; k++){
        //console.log(lines[k]);
        string += lines[k];
    }
    console.log(string);  //log the same string outside the loop and the fatal error goes away
}
```

Comment: what is the length of your files array? in the first piece of code you are using two for loops which might flush tooo many requests together causing out of memory

Comment: 500 files.  Each about 1.8mb

Comment: what you can do is dont flush all files together. What you can do is use async.eachSeries which will control the loop from flush requests.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
do npm install async --save
var async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(files , filesIteration , finishIteration);

function filesIteration(file , callBack){
    readFile(file , callBack);
}


function readFile(data , cb){
    var lines = fs.readFileSync(data).toString().split('\n');
    for(var k = 0; k < lines.length; k++){
        console.log(lines[k]);
        if(k === lines.length - 1){
            cb();
        }
    }
}

function finishIteration(){
    console.log('all files processed');
}
```

Comment: If you use `async`, then you shouldn't use the `fs` module synchronously.

Comment: you can use fs asynchronously aswell. all i have done is controlling the upper loop so too many request are not flushed. @Bergi. There are many ways to write the code in readFile function async and sync both will work and yes i agree async file read will work more better and there wont be any chanes of memory leaks